# Javascript not working in Safari but working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have created a series of drop downs that feed into a couple custom sentences. A user will select options from the drop downs, select submit, and code will generate sentences with their specific inputs. Essentially, the sentences are based on what the user inputs. My code seems to work great in Chrome; however, it does not work in Safari.

The error seems to arise due to input6. I created a Let for input6 and while chrome accepts it Safari does not. Safari web inspector says "unexpected identifier: 'input 6'.

[image]

Any ideas?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
 <title>Hi</title>

 <style type="text/css">
  table,td,th {margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto}
  .display {display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;}
  p {text-align: center;}
  textarea {display: block;margin-left:auto;margin-right: auto;}
 </style>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function sentence() {
    document.getElementById("s1").value = "";// reset
    document.getElementById("s1").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("r1").style.display = "block";
    if (document.getElementById("z1").value == "") {
      alert("Year, Make, and Model are needed");
      document.getElementById("z1").focus();}
      else if (document.getElementById("z2").value == "") {
      alert("Mileage is needed");}
      else if (document.getElementById("z3").value == "") {
      alert("Exterior color is needed");}
    else {
      const input1 = document.getElementById("z1").value;
      const input2 = document.getElementById("z2").value;
      const input3 = document.getElementById("z3").value;
      const input4 = document.getElementById("z4").value;
      const input5 = document.getElementById("z10").value;
      let input6;
      if (document.getElementById("z4").value == "okay") {
        input6 = "It has a few " + input5 + ". ";
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("z4").value=="excellent"){
          input6 = "It has no " + input5 + ". ";
        }
        else {
          input6 = "";
        }

      document.getElementById("s1").value =
        "Up for sale is a " + input1 + " with " + input2 + " miles. It is finished in "
        + input3 + ". It is in " + input4 + " shape. " + input6 + "I have owned this car for six years.";

    }
  }

  function reset() {
    document.getElementById("s1").value = "";
  }


  function hide() {
    document.getElementById("s1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("r1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("z5").style.display = "none";
  }

      function condition ()
      {
        if (document.getElementById("z4").value == "okay") {
          document.getElementById("z5").style.display = "block";
          }
        else if (document.getElementById("z4").value == "excellent") {
          document.getElementById("z5").style.display = "block";
          }
        else {
          document.getElementById("z5").style.display = "none";
          }
      }

 </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="hide()">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="z1" placeholder="Year, Make, Model" name="name" maxlength="100">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="z2" placeholder="Mileage" name="name" maxlength="100">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="z3" placeholder="Exterior Color" name="name" maxlength="100">
        </td>
        <td>
          <div onclick="condition()">
          <select name="condition" id="z4"  class="chosen-select">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Condition</option>
            <option value="excellent">Excellent</option>
            <option value="good">Good</option>
            <option value="okay">Okay</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="z5">
          <select name="condition" id="z10" class="chosen-select">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Why?</option>
            <option value="scratches">Scratches</option>
            <option value="dents">Dents</option>
            <option value="mechanical issues">Mechanical Issues</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="z2" placeholder="Test" name="name" maxlength="100">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <div class="display">
      <button onclick="sentence()"> Submit </button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="100" id="s1"></textarea>
    <br>

    <div class="display">
      <button onclick="reset()" id="r1">Reset</button>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your snippet is running without error in Safari for me. Your error suggests that there is a space in `input 6`, but there's not in the snipper.

Comment: Replace let input6; to var input6; . it doesn't support in Safari

Comment: @VindhyachalKumar that works great! Thanks!